# mocking randomnly generated data in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I have a model where it is accepting a set of parameters and tries to do encryption to one parameter and pass the encrypted data to another method.

```
def post(key, value, data)

    business_guid = SecureRandom.uuid

    queue_item = "#{key}^#{value}^#{data}"
    Queue.create_queue_item(business, Finance, "medium", 2011-12-20, "abc", data)
end
```

So here I need to mock the data in my rspec and since everytime it creates a random business_guid, my mocked data fails with the newly generated one. So could you please tell me how can I handle it.

Answer (score 2):

(Not sure I understand you correctly)

Why not just to stub it

```
SecureRandom.stub(uuid: 'some_uuid')
```

Comment: Still works in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) (which I highly recommend), you can use a simple Minitest stub:

```
SecureRandom.stub :uuid, "whateveryouwant" do
  SecureRandom.uuid #=> "whateveryouwant"
end
```

I prefer these because the **stub goes away once the block is done**! So great.